# (Proof verification) $\pi: X\to Y$ birational with $X$ smooth implies $\pi_*O_X=O_Y$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, algebraic-geometry

As the title suggests, I am looking for a confirmation or falsification of my proof of the following

> Let $\pi: X\to Y$ be a birational map of algebraic varieties over the complex numbers with $X$ smooth. Then, $\pi_XO_X=O_Y$.

My idea goes as follows.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are birational, there exists open subsets $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ such that $\pi: U\to V$ is an isomorphism. In particular, $O_X(U)=(\pi_*O_X)(V)=O_Y(V)$. What we have to show is that $$\pi^*: O_Y\to \pi_*O_X,\ f\mapsto \pi^*f:=f\circ \pi$$ is surjective (since its obviously injective and a morphism). Thus take any $g\in O_X(X)$, that is, a holomorphic map $X\to \mathbb C$. Since $O_X(U)=O_Y(V)$, $$g\mid_U=(\pi^*f)\mid_U$$ for some $f\in O_Y(Y)$. But we are then given two holomorphic functions $g,\pi^*f$ that coincide on an open subset of a complex manifold (since we assumed $X$ to be smooth) and the identity principle then yields that $g=\pi^*f$ and $\pi^*$ is surjective.

---

I was unable to find any issue with the proof. However, I also have Zariski's Main Theorem in mind, stating that for a birational map $\pi: X\to Y$ of algebraic varieties one needs normality of $Y$ to deduce $\pi_*O_X=O_Y$, which is a condition on the *target*, whereas the proof given above seems imposes a condition only on the *domain*. However, ZMT is more general for varieties over other fields and none of $X,Y$ is required to be smooth.

Comments on this are very welcome! If you find any (even small) issue with the proof, please drop a comment. Thanks!

Comment: For the surjectivity of $\pi^*:O_Y\to \pi_*O_X$, you said that $g|_U=(\pi^*f)|_U$ for some $f\in O_Y(Y)$. Why is that so ? You can only get that $g|_U=\pi^*f$ for some $f\in O_Y(V)$. Why such a $f$ would extend ?

Comment: Of course, if you want a counter example of your claim, simply take $Y=\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ (a nodal curve) and $X=\operatorname{Spec}k[t]$ its normalization (with $t=y/x$). The map $O_Y\to \pi_*O_X$ is simply the map $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)\to k[t]$ which maps $x\mapsto t^2-1$ and $y\mapsto t^3-t$. Clearly this is not an isomorphism.

Comment: I was thinking that since every $f\in O_Y(Y)$ gives rise to a function $\pi^*f\in O_X(X)$. Now if we are given any $g\in O_X(X)$, we can find $f\in O_Y(V)$ such that $\pi^*f=g\mid_U$ and that we can take $f$ to be the restriction of a global function on $Y$. I see that the normalisation provides a counterexample, but it still isn't clear to me where my argument fails.

Comment: If you consider the normalization of the node, and $x\in X$ is a point lying over the node, Cauchy Integral Formula gives that $g(x)=\int_\gamma \frac{g(z)}{z-x}dz$ which only depends on a neighbourhood of the point $x$ and not the point itself. Also here, $g$ and $\pi^*f$ coincide so we would get extension of $\pi^*f$ for free if we can't assume it.

Comment: Because the $f$ cannot be extended to $Y$ as I said in my first comment. With the notation of my second comment, take the function $t$ in $\pi_*O_X$. Then $t|_U$ (the curve without the node), it is indeed $y/x$, but this function does not extend as a function in $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is not true, and the following counterexample is good to keep in mind:

Let $X$ be two copies of $\Bbb A^1$ and let $Y$ be $V(xy)\subset \Bbb A^2$, with the map $f$ acting as $t\mapsto (0,t)$ and $u\mapsto (u,0)$ where $t,u$ are coordinates on the different copies of $\Bbb A^1$. Then certainly removing the origins of both lines in $X$ and the crossing point in $Y$ gives an isomorphism, so this is a birational map. But one can see immediately that the stalk of $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is rank 2 at the crossing point of $Y$.

To get at the particular point where your proof breaks, consider the map $g:X\to \Bbb A^1$,  the map taking the value $1$ on one line and $0$ on the other. Following your procedure, you obtain a function $f$ on $Y$ without the crossing point which is $0$ on one axis and $1$ on the other - this cannot be extended to a function on the whole variety. So your claim here is false.

The essential difficulty here is that sections of a line bundle on a normal variety can be extended over a codimension two set, but not necessarily a codimension one set. For your claim to be true, you'll need to enforce exactly the conditions of Zariski's Main Theorem.

I should also mention that the question of$X$ is smooth and $f:X\to Y$ is birational implying $f_*\mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_Y$ is awfully close to the condition of [rational singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_singularity). If you end up studying more algebraic geometry, this class is a particularly well-behaved bunch of singularities.

Comment: Your example was really helpful, thank you very much. Together with the comments by @Roland, I do now understand why it doesn't work. I will definitely keep your example in mind!

Comment: By the way, can $\pi_*O_X=O_Y$ then only happen if $Y$ is normal or $\pi$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: No, there's a wide variety of situations where it can happen. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63301/when-will-the-pushforward-of-a-structure-sheaf-still-be-a-structure-sheaf